# How html bundling work with $.component.html files into angular 2 huge application?

Tags: angular, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am new with angular 2 and webpack and have a basic conceptual knowledge about it. i am working in a project where I have 100's of html files. **I am unable to understand how does webpack will bundle html files** ? I have html files with it's respective components. So following are the questions, running in my mind :-

1. Is webpack bundle html files with js files ?, if it does so how ?
2. If it will simply copy all the static files along their respective path and folder into the output folder?, if it does so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both question answer is::

Webpack bundle html files content into js file itself.....

Let say:

```
@Component({
    selector : 'bug-edit',
    templateUrl : require('./bug-edit')
})
```

So when webpack transform this to es2015 it will become

```
template: "<b>All content in html file</b>"
```

So in short webpack bundle js and html in one file...associate to url...

Comment: Using [angular2-template-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-template-loader) you don't have to `require()` the template anymore.